# Sending data from one activity to dynamic list in other activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have tried using intent function but the app crashes whenever I try to come on the dashboard screen

```
public class Dashboard extends Activity {

    Button add1;
    private ListView lv;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("txtData","");     

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // Instantiating an array list (you don't need to do this, 
        // you already have yours).
    List<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    your_array_list.add(message);


        // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a 
        // first parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your 
        // array as a third parameter.
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this,  R.layout.list, your_array_list );

    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 



    add1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 
    add1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),AddDevice.class);
    startActivity(i);
            }

         });
     }

}
```

I am trying to send data from `AddDevice.java` to `Dashbaord` and get that data to a list which should be visible on dashbaord, This is my `AddDevice.java`:

```
public class AddDevice extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);   

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),Dashboard.class);

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra("txtData", message);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it crashes, show the stacktrace from logcat. Also you're creating an Intent and then do nothing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using getBaseContext() inside an onClick on listener? Please change it to getApplicationContext() or Dashboard.this

If you would check logcat you will find the error:

> "The constructor Intent(Context, Class) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (new 
>    View.OnClickListener(){}, Class)"